# Matrix for tensor transform

Tags: tensor-calculus

If a vector's components transform according to $x'_{i} = L_{ij} x_{j}$ then $L_{ij} = e'_{i}.e_{j}$ since $x'_{i} =  e'_{i}.(e_{j} x_{j})$.

(The following problem is from Riley, Hobson and Bence, "Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering: A Comprehensive Guide" problem 26.2)

In the original frame,
 $$\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\
                                                                                                                                0 \\
                                                                                                                                 0
                                                                                                                             \end{pmatrix}$$

and in a rotated frame, the components of a vector $ \mathbf{A}$ are given by $$  \mathbf{A'} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
                                        0 \\
                                        \frac{1}{2}
                                        \end{pmatrix}$$

and

in the original frame, $$\mathbf{B} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\
                                                                                                                                1 \\
                                                                                                                                 0
                                                                                                                             \end{pmatrix}$$

and in the rotated frame, the components of another vector $ \mathbf{B}$ are given by  $$  \mathbf{B'} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{{1}}{2} \\
                                        0 \\
                                        \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
                                        \end{pmatrix}$$

I want to find the matrix that gives you the components of any vector in the rotated frame if you have the components in the original frame. In other words, I want the matrix $ \mathbf{L}$ such that $ \mathbf{x'} = \mathbf{L} \mathbf{x}$. Now from tensor analysis, we know that the $ L_{ij} = e'_i.e_j $ where $e'_i $ = ith basis vector in rotated frame and $e_j $ = jth basis vector in original frame. I let $ e_1 = \mathbf{A} $, $ e'_1 = \mathbf{A'}$, $e_2 = \mathbf{B}$ and $e'_2 = \mathbf{B'}$
And in the original frame, $$\mathbf{e_3} = \begin{pmatrix}
                                                                                                                                0 \\
                                                                                                                                 0 \\
                                                                                                                                     1
                                                                                                                             \end{pmatrix}$$

And in the rotated frame,

$$\mathbf{e_3}' = \begin{pmatrix}
                                                                                                                                a \\
                                                                                                                                 b \\
                                                                                                                                     c
                                                                                                                             \end{pmatrix}$$

I used the fact that $\mathbf{L}$ has a determinant of 1 and that it has orthonormal rows to find $a,b$ and $ c $.

$$ \mathbf{L} = \begin{pmatrix} \overline{e}'_1. \overline{e}_1 & \overline{e}'_1. \overline{e}_2 & \overline{e}'_1. \overline{e}_3\\ \overline{e}'_2. \overline{e}_1 & \overline{e}'_2. \overline{e}_2 & \overline{e}'_2. \overline{e}_1 \\ \overline{e}'_3. \overline{e}_1 & \overline{e}'_3. \overline{e}_2 & \overline{e}'_3. \overline{e}_3 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{3} & 0 & 1 \\ -1  & 0 & \sqrt{3}\\ 0 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}   $$

This, however, is not the correct matrix. It is the INVERSE of the correct matrix. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you say, 'we know from tensor analysis that...' Have you considered where the rule you state comes from?

Comment: If our vector components transform according to $x'_{i} = L_{ij} x_{j} $, then $L_{ij} = e'_{i}.e_{j}$, since $x'_{i} =  e'_{i}.(e_{j} x_{j})$

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found my mistake here. The $\overline{e'_{i}}$ refer to the *new* basis vectors (i.e. the basis vectors in the *rotated* frame) and *NOT* the components of the old basis vectors in the *rotated* frame. Hence we have:

$$ \overline{e'_{1}} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ \overline{e'_{2}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ \overline{e'_{3}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

in the *NEW* frame. Furthermore, to evaluate the dot products we need components in the same frame. Now we know the components of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ in the rotated frame. So, for example,

$$ \overline{e'_2}.\overline{e_1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}.\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{3} \\0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}  = 0$$.

and so on and so forth.